# If conditions for Python dictionaries

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

So I have a string which is converted into a dictionary called test and takes the form:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
```

Now while creating the dictionary, the availablilty of the `"c":"3"` key-pair, depends on a some condition; so there are cases when the dictionary simply reads as:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2"}
```

I have an `if` condition which checks for the existence of the `"c"` key and gives some output based on it. The condition is as follows:

```
if (test["c"]):
            print "Hello world!!"
```

This has no else condition. The problem arises when the 3rd key-value pair isn't in the dictionary. Running the code gives the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 14, in test
      if test["c"]:
KeyError: 'c'
```

May I know what I can do to resolve this and what to correct in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `in` to check if the key is in the dictionary:

```
if "c" in test:
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `test['c']` try to use `test.get('c')`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key is in the dictionary as others suggested, but another solution is to use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).